# Is it possible to call/trigger Domino rest web service from domino agents or any other backend processess?

Tags: rest, post, xpages

I have a REST custom web service written in java using xpages.

It works well when it is called from the browser, but when it is triggered from the scheduled tasks/agents it fails.

Is it possible to call the domino rest web service which defined in the xpage from Agent or any other scheduled process.

Below are couple of error messages I recieved in the log

State data not available for /services because no control tree was found in the cache.
Cannot use BufferedReader while ServletInputStream is in use

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things to watch out for:

- Rest services are by definition stateless, so make sure you have `nostate` as attribute of your XPage
- You only can have a Writer or an OutputStream, so use only one. See [my article on XAgents revisited](https://wissel.net/blog/2010/12/rendering-your-own-output-in-xpages-revisited.html)
- Authentication is always a headache, so configure your REST endpoint to allow basic auth (setting in internet site configuration)
- LotusScript doesn't do network so you would use `@Formula` or Java in a scheduled agent
- Simplest form is a Formula agent using `@UrlOpen("https://username:password@yourserver.com/yourdb.nsf/somexpage.xsp/yourrest");`
- When you pack your logic into a bean, you can use the [OpenNTF Domino Api](https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino) to define a XOTS scheduled task. Most advanced option (in many meanings of that word)

Hope that helps, let us know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment, let me get back to you on my next working day.

Comment: Added no state and the Rest API started working with Basic Authentication.
Tested the Rest API url from C# Code and it works good.
Java is throwing the below exception now.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Comment: Added no state and the Rest API started working with Basic Authentication.

Tested the Rest API url from C# Code and it works good and able to POST successfully by creating documents.

Java is now throwing new exception now.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake.

What do you mean by only one of Writer or an OutputStream?

By the way since the API ran good for C#, pretty sure that the API is working for some set of people, so nothing wrong with the customRestService, will update you what is wrong with Java code soon

Thanks,
James